# Menu Fixed Scroll Top

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu fiz esse código para que quando eu rolasse a página o MENU ficasse fixado no Topo. Ou seja, sempre a vista do usuário.

```
var nav = $('#outermainmenu');
var lia = $('.sf-menu > li, .sf-menu > li > a');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 440) {
        nav.addClass("menu-fixed");
        lia.addClass("menu-fixed");
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("menu-fixed");
        lia.removeClass("menu-fixed");
    }
});
```

Esse código acima funciona. Mas apenas quando a altura for maior que 440px, visto que é a altura do meu slider. Mas eu gostaria que não fosse assim. Porquê tem páginas que meu slider muda de altura.

Não quero ficar verificando no meu script a altura do slider e definindo um scrollTop.

Tem como eu fazer isso verificando se o menu está em TOP 0 ? O menu fica depois do slider de 440px de altura.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi. Sempre assim, quando eu posto, depois encontro a solução.
A linha que faz a diferença é essa:
`var num = $('#outermainmenu').offset().top;`

Pega a posição em Top do Menu. Verifico se a rolagem **bateu** no menu e aplico meu CSS.

```
var nav = $('#outermainmenu');
var lia = $('.sf-menu > li, .sf-menu > li > a');
var num = $('#outermainmenu').offset().top;

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
         lia.addClass('menu-fixed');
         nav.addClass('menu-fixed');
     }
     else {
         num = $('#outermainmenu').offset().top;
         lia.removeClass('menu-fixed');
         nav.removeClass('menu-fixed');
     }
});
```