# Menu acompanha conteúdo na rolagem de tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

No OLX tem um menu do lado esquerdo que após certa rolagem o mesmo acompanha o conteúdo: https://pr.olx.com.br/roupas-e-calcados/calcas?cond=1

O atual HTML desenvolvido com Twitter-Bootstrap 3 está assim:

```
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4'>
    <div class='box-menu'>
        <ul class='menu'>
           <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8'>
    [conteudo]
</div>
```

**Apóx Xpx de rolagem, como conseguir esse efeito?**

Tentei de dois modos, o primeiro foi sugerido em [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp), mais trabalhoso e aparentava resolver meu problema.

O segundo foi usando [propriedades CSS](https://willianjusten.com.br/menu-sticky-e-smooth-scroll-com-css-puro/), mas não tive sucesso.

**O menu fica fixo e não se mexe.**

Antes de marcar como duplicada, Já vi algumas publicações no SOpt mas estão incompletas.

Aqui colaram apenas o código JS que aplica a classe, tentaram explicar como fazer com o CSS mas nada concreto, sem exemplos.
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254053/menu-fixo-ap%c3%b3s-rolagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254053/menu-fixo-ap%C3%B3s-rolagem)

Aqui o próprio publicador resolveu e respondeu a correção com código incompleto.
[Menu Fixed Scroll Top](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65902/menu-fixed-scroll-top?rq=1)

Essa outra o jsfiddle está com vários bugs
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129367/menu-fixo-com-jquery-em-determinada-rolagem-scroll-da-p%c3%a1gina?noredirect=1&lq=1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129367/menu-fixo-com-jquery-em-determinada-rolagem-scroll-da-p%C3%A1gina?noredirect=1&lq=1)

O outro menu é atribuído como fixo permanente. [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365971/menu-lateral-fixo-na-esquerda-com-conte%c3%bado-na-direita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365971/menu-lateral-fixo-na-esquerda-com-conte%C3%BAdo-na-direita)

Comment: Olha se é isso que vc precisa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/283097/como-posso-fixar-esse-menu-no-topo/283104#283104

Comment: Outro modelo, agora na lateral https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328957/div-fixada-quando-chega-no-top/328966#328966 tem várias opções apenas com CSS usando position:sticky, basta vc pesquisar e vai ver....

Comment: A primeira opção adaptei fácil e deu certo, valeu!

Comment: Massa, já que resolveu fechei como Duplicada ok. Abs